# Eclipse plugin for exporting svn diff to JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm looking for SVN plugin, which can export diff files between 2 revisions to runnable jar file.

So I will give it to another man, who just run it on test/production server, and jar automatically will update project with exported diff files.

It's easy to write command tool like I need, but I'm looking for Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right my issue is similar to yours.

Back in Eclipse 3.2 (ish) in the synchronize perspective, you could select locally changed files, then do File > Export and choose JAR, and it would select the files for you.  Now it doesn't.

If you want just the text diff, it's easy.  Just use the create patch option.

If you want to create a jar containing the changed files - which I find useful for recording the changes for a chunk of work, or saving the alterations to a branch when I want to work on another, then its possible but unnecessarily laboured.  (Works with Indigo)

Exporting changes in eclipse Synchronize view:

1. Select all of them in the synchronize view
2. Right Click and choose Show In > Project Explorer
3. In the Project Explorer that appears, all the files should be selected.  Some may be collapsed in their parent package.  Use the + to make sure they are all visible and selected.
4. right click in the Project Explorer and choose Export > Java > Jar File, or drag the files into an explorer window if you want them in a flat directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just not possible (at least, not using SVN / text diffs).

SVN/diff work with text files. The result with diff is a excerpt with only the lines changed in a file (in this class a .java source file). These files cannot even be compiled because they are not java code (even if the lines themselves are).

What you may do is use svn log to check which files have changed, retrieve the associated .class files and use them to patch the server. Do not know if there is any tool that makes that automatically, though (and it is complicated as often the .class files are not commited into subversion).

Comment: By "diff" I meant "difference" ;( Most of svn tools can extract changed files between 2 revisions to some folder. But I'm looking for some, which can pack it into runnable jar file, which extracts exported files.

Comment: Anyway, you will end with isolated .java classes. You'd need your tool to automatically compile these .java to get the .class.

Comment: You will have to do a full build (due to the dependencies of the classes) and extract only classes which sources have changed.